# Blank Sitemap.xml

Tags: magento2, admin-panel, sitemaps

I configured the sitemap configurations to update automatic my sitemap.xml and then I generated a sitemap via admin panel, as you can see below:

[image: Magento2 Sitemap XML blank]

My Sitemap:

[image: Magento2 Sitemap XML]

How to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

You might use a different path in the admin panel, it seems like you are using **NGINX** so you need to specify the path as the image below `/pub/` because using **NGINX** it is your root folder accessible via the browser.

[image: Magento 2 Sitemap Blank Solution]

Answer (score 0):

Firstly set path for your sitemap generation. If that doesn't fix it, try using Xdebug on **\Magento\Sitemap\Model\Sitemap.php generateXml() method** and see what data it returns.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using **Magento ver. 2.1.8** there is a bug that Magento generates the sitemap and robots.txt files in `http` directory rather than in the `http/pub`.

If that's the case and you are using NginX, add this to the configuration file to set the path to your

```
# robots
location = /robots.txt {
    alias /var/www/example.com/html/robots.txt;
}

# sitemap
location = /sitemap.xml {
    alias /var/www/example.com/html/sitemap.xml;
}
```

Also, you can find the bug fix here: https://github.com/magento/magento2/pull/9094